How to report the between study variance through tau2 for vaccine effectiveness using R's metafor?
My colleague and I have been performing a meta analysis using R's metafor package and the rma.uni function to estimate pooled odds ratios. We feed rma log-transformed odds ratios and corresponding variances. Method is REML.
After performing the meta analysis we backtransform to normal odds ratios ($OR=10^{log(OR)}$) and then convert these to vaccine effectiveness (VE) values given in percentages using $ VE = (1-OR)*100$.
However, when we extract the between study standard variance $τ^2$ using $tau2, the unit of $τ$ is based on having log ORs as outcome estimate.
For $I^2$ this does not matter since it is a relative measure shown in percentages, but since $τ^2$ is the standard variance they only make sense i.c.w. the estimated log ORs, right?
How can we convert the obtained $τ^2$ values so they make sense when putting them next to the VE percentages. Would we simply convert it similarly to converting ORs to VE, like:
$τ^2_{VE}=(1-τ^2_{OR})*100 $
Or is it more complicated? E.g., do we also need to backtransform the $tau2?

You cannot transform the $\tau^2$ value that way. Also, most people will struggle to understand the estimate of $\tau^2$ (or some transformed version thereof if this was possible) in the first place. Instead, it would be better to provide a prediction interval, which will reflect the amount of heterogeneity in a much more understandable manner. Here is an example using the BCG vaccine dataset:
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="OR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)
res
predict(res, transf=function(x) (1-exp(x))*100)

Note that you can use the predict() function to automate these calculations. The 95% prediction interval (pi.lb and pi.ub) is very wide here (and suggests that there may be circumstances where the vaccine increases the risk of infection, although I would tend to interpret this as circumstances where the vaccine is not effective).
Sidenote: escalc() uses the natural log when computing the log-transformed odds/risk ratios, which is much more common than using logs with base 10.

I already suspected such a thing. Makes me wonder, using prediction intervals, can we still quantify how much of the variance is explained by heterogeneity? E.g., through a comparison with the confidence intervals? Or can we only visually inspect the level of heterogeneity in the variance here?

Comparing the PI with the CI is akin to the $R$ statistic that Higgins and Thompson (2002) describe. Besides $I^2$ and $H^2$, it's another way to quantify the amount of heterogeneity.
